# Not able to upload large files to azure blob storage using multer API in node

Tags: node.js, azure, multer

I am trying to upload large files to azure blob storage from node js application. I have an post method where I will be getting multiple file(large - more than gb) and i need to upload them to blob storage as it is. I am able to upload small files but for big files i am getting connection timeou ECONTIMEOUT or ECONNRESET error.
Please help.

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: Could you update your code in your post to help resolving your issue?